# Pentaho Report Grouping & Hide/Show Elements

Tags: report, grouping, pentaho, subreport

I am using Pentaho Report Designer & BI server 5.0.1.

I'm having a report like,

I need to show insurance coverage details and risk details under that coverage for an insured( one insured can have many coverages and each coverage can have many risks).
We are having 20 different coverages and each having different elements and different risk details.

I thought of using three groups with

```
Insured at Group1
--> Coverage Details at Group2
    --> Risk Details at Group3
```

my doubt is,

1. can we show different elements in Group2 based on coverage type?
2. can we done this using groups or do we need to use sub reports for each coverage type? not sure what will be suitable for my requirement?
3. I need to conditionally hide/show columns, but 'invisibleConsumesSpace' property is not working in PRD 5.0.1. need some alternative for that.

Answer (score 0):

The invisible consumes space property must be set on the band that contains the element. It governs how the band interprets the visible flag of its clients.

If all your data is contained in one result-set, then the normal way of showing different record types is via using a conditional visibility function to show/hide the appropriate elements.

You can find an example of that in "Income statement" sample, but here is the general approach:

(1) Set your details- and other band that should display multiple record types to layout "block".
(2) Add a sub-band for each record type.
(3) On each subband, add a formula (green plus on the styles) to the "visible" style element that returns true if the record should be shown, and false otherwise.

Then simply fill in your elements for each band.

Note that this method does not easily allow you to change the grouping within this structure. If you need different group configuration based on the record type, you might find it easier to use subreport.